# Dual monitors with different resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, vga

I'm on an old LG r405 with the built in graphics card:
Nvidia g86 GeForce8600 gs rev a1

Seeing as it has a VGA output, I figured that it'd be nice to use my HD screen (benq senseye g2222hdl)
It works perfectly with my OSX partition, but booting up with Ubuntu doesn't work at all.

Initially when I installed 12.04 clean everything was fine, except for the screens being swapped left to right.
When I swapped places in the setup application everything started going bad.
The screen content was scrambled totally, I couldn't even see where the mouse was at to reboot the computer and had to hold the power button down.

If I forget to unplug the screen when booting into Ubuntu, the resolution of the Laptop screen is set really high, but as soon as I log in, the contents get scrambled again.

Please advice.

/M

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04 comes with a default display setting application(Displays). Please select the highest resolutions for both of your displays and keep mirror display unchecked, also select the monitor in which you want the unity launcher and apply.

Comment: Dear lord, that helped! I don't know why it didn't work before but now it's perfectly fine. o_O Thanks a million!

Comment: Ahem.. I'm afraid I was a little too quick to celebrate. I've done a few reboots now, and even tho I could successfully get the two monitors to play ball, as soon as I reboot I'll have the scrambledness again. I can get it up and running again, but Only if I boot the computer with the monitor unplugged, logging in and then following your steps once more..

Comment: Ya I have also faced the same issues ;). May be that is an Ubuntu bug, so keep the settings the same and unplug the VGA cable before rebooting ;) . This will be fixed in later releases.

Comment: Actually it stopped working alltogether after a few more reboots and experimenting. Now I can't have the screen plugged in at all, this makes the computer look like a tv set without reception, except for more colors.

Maybe it's time to do a proper re-install, maybe try a different dist.

Thx
/M